# Removing favorite styles does not work in Lion’s TextEdit

Tags: macos, textedit

In TextEdit on OS X 10.7 Lion, I want to remove some custom text styles I created previously (see screenshot). I have tried the “Remove from favorites” button in the “Show Styles > Favourite Styles” dialog, however this only removes them until TextEdit is reopened. How do I delete the styles permanently?

[image: TextEdit styles dropdown]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have run into a bug in Lion’s version of TextEdit. For reasons unknown, the designers of TextEdit opted for [storing favorite styles in the global preferences file](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=60986) (`~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`) when they introduced the feature. They might have intended to create a user global stored styles system for [NSText](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/TextUILayer.html) based rich text editors (not the only oddity of the system – [this post](http://pagesfaq.blogspot.com/2008/05/textedit-and-styles.html) has a good write-up of TextEdit’s style implementation). This has worked up to and including OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

In OS X 10.7 Lion however, TextEdit has been [sandboxed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EnablingAppSandbox/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1) (*sandboxing* means, in layman’s terms: the operating system only grants an application discrete rights to access the file system, network, OS services etc. as defined by the app – so called *entitlements*. Anything a sandboxed application tries beyond that what is covered by its entitlements will be denied and logged by the sandbox daemon `sandbox`). A look at the log, where you will find an entry similar to this one

```
02.11.11 14:44:54,659 sandboxd: ([73342]) TextEdit(73342) deny file-write-create /Users/<user>/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist.c2n4nCb
```

each time you try to store a new favorite style shows that writing to `.GlobalPreferences` is not among TextEdit’s entitlements. **The result: Lion’s TextEdit can neither store new favorite styles*, nor delete ones written ether by previous versions of TextEdit (your case).**

To get rid of the old styles, you need to remove the `NSFavoriteStyles` key from the global preferences list. If you have Xcode installed, invoking

```
open ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
```

will open the file in Xcode’s plist Editor, where you can remove / modify it manually. If you don’t,

```
defaults delete -g NSFavoriteStyles
```

will get rid of all stored (“favorite”) styles.

---

* it might look like it does, as these are stored in memory while TextEdit runs, and with Lion’s revamped process management, it is difficult to tell when textEdit **really** quits. Still, once it does, the favorite styles disappear.

---

*ADDENDUM: Reported as a bug to Apple (OpenRadar [rdar://10385163](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1421401)).

According to Apple Developer Relations, this bug has been quashed as of OS X 10.8*

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately that's not working for me-  if I quit with cmd+alt-Q after closing the untitled doc with red button and then reopen, the styles are still there- I can make a screengrab video if you want.

Comment: @MachineElf: um, you are right – apparently, my copy of TextEdit is truck with amnesia: it forgets all styles between starts, even favorite ones. One question: are your styles predating the upgrade to Lion? or at least the 10.7.2 update maybe?

Comment: Haha! Yes I did create them before updating I believe, the mystery deepens ... thanks again

Comment: @MachineElf: no, in fact, that **solves** the mystery – I’ll edit my answer as soon as I have am little more time.

Comment: @MachineElf: Answer edited, new solution.

Answer (score 0):

@kopischke, nice explanation, I had been wondering about this issue for some time.

A little workaround I found useful:
It seems [MacJournal](http://www.marinersoftware.com/products/macjournal/) uses the same favorite styles as TextEdit (that's one place where those global styles are actually useful). As MacJournal is not (yet) sandboxed, I could edit (add/delete) my favorite styles from there and they were saved correctly. And after that I could use them in TextEdit also.

Answer (score 0):

For all tweaking their Favorite Styles (aka NSFavoriteStyles) in following Mac OS's after Snow Leopard like Mountain Lion or Mavericks: The settings (NSFavoriteStyles) have been moved to:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppKit.TextFavorites.plist
```